# self joining the same table to group rows together that share a substring together

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has multiple rows that share a substring in a certain column and I want to group them together.

For example I might have

```
ID | Service     | Function
__________________________________________
 1 | abc1234hgf  | Create
 2 | bvc8554mnb  | Create
 3 | cxz1234poi  | Update
```

I am trying to write the query to group rows that share the substring of the number in Service (so 1234 in this example) **and** have both an update and a create entry so this would be the result:

```
ID  | Service | Function
________________________
 1  | 1234    |  Create
 3  | 1234    |  Update
```

So I tried writing a query that does a self join because Update only happens if there is a create row already so I thought I could get backwards: find rows with Update entry, take the service substring from there, and join it to find the rest of the creates.

```
SELECT a.id, a.service, a.function
FROM audits a
INNER JOIN audits b
ON a.service = SUBSTR(b.service, 4, 8);
```

now this gives me all the 4 digit #s grouped together, but I want to narrow down on WHERE function in ('update', 'create'). When I try either though I get null.

Am I on the right path here?

Comment: What's the logic? Do you want to extract the substring with 4 chars long exactly at the middle, or all digits within the string ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan 4 characters in the middle every time. I selected answer down below though, thanks!

Comment: OK, you're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.id, SUBSTR(a.service, 4, 8) as service, a.function
FROM audits a
WHERE a.function IN ('create', 'update') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM audits a2
              WHERE SUBSTR(a2.service, 4, 8) = SUBSTR(a.service, 4, 8) AND
                    a2.function IN ('create', 'update') AND
                    a2.function <> a.function
             );
```

Comment: This works! I just had to put ORDER BY a.service at the end to group the creates and updates of the same service # to be one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a join; instead you can use analytic functions to do it in a single table scan:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE audits ( ID, Service, Function ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'abc1234hgf', 'Create' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'bvc8554mnb', 'Create' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'cxz1234poi', 'Update' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT id,
       service,
       function
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         SUBSTR( service, 4, 4 ) AS service,
         function,
         COUNT( CASE function WHEN 'Create' THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY SUBSTR( service, 4, 4 ) ) AS num_create,
         COUNT( CASE function WHEN 'Update' THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY SUBSTR( service, 4, 4 ) ) AS num_update
  FROM   audits
)
WHERE  num_create > 0
AND    num_update > 0
```

**Output**:

```
ID | SERVICE | FUNCTION
-: | :------ | :-------
 1 | 1234    | Create  
 3 | 1234    | Update
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f0f0989970bf678c4bde0adf1b7899d6)*

Answer (score 0):

```
with t (ID, Service, func) as (
  select 1 ,'abc1234hgf','Create' from dual union all
  select 6 ,'abc1234hgf','Create' from dual union all
  select 7 ,'abc1234hgf','Create' from dual union all
  select 9 ,'abc1234hgf','Create' from dual union all
  select 10 ,'abc1234hgf','Create' from dual union all
  select 2 ,'bvc8554mnb','Create' from dual union all
  select 3 ,'cxz1234poi','Update' from dual union all
  select 8 ,'cxz1234poi','Update' from dual union all
  select 4 ,'bvc8551mnb','Create' from dual union all
  select 5 ,'bvc8552mnq','Create' from dual 
)
select id, service, func from (
  select id, service, func, idx, rn, count(*) over (partition by idx, rn) cnt from (
    select t.*
    , substr(service, 4, 4) idx
    , row_number() over(partition by substr(service, 4, 4), decode(func, 'Create', 1, 'Update', 2) order by id) rn 
    from t
  )
)
where cnt = 2
order by idx, id
;

        ID SERVICE    FUNC 
---------- ---------- ------
         1 abc1234hgf Create 
         3 cxz1234poi Update 
         6 abc1234hgf Create 
         8 cxz1234poi Update
```

Comment: Why does `1` and `6` appear in your results but `7`, `9` and `10` do not?

Comment: Grouping at max one 'Create' service to one 'Update' service matched by the substring.